# python-CUDA is disabled due to setting NUMBA_DISABLE_CUDA=1 in the environment

Tags: python, cuda

This is the first time when i try to use cuda in python, so i've followed up some tutorials regarding on how to set it up...but i ended up with this error:

```
numba.cuda.cudadrv.error.CudaSupportError: Error at driver init: 
CUDA is disabled due to setting NUMBA_DISABLE_CUDA=1 in the environment, or because CUDA is unsupported on 32-bit systems.:
```

I am runnig a x64 Windows version and i've checked the python version too (which is also on x64). I am using a Nvidia gtx 960m, with the latest drivers.

I've tried to search for this problem for over two weeks now, but didn't find any solution that might work

Also i will insert the code here, but i don't think that here is the problem:

```
@vectorize(["float32(float32, float32)"], target='cuda')
def test(a,b):
    return a+b

def main():

    a=np.arange(1,10,dtype=np.float32)
    b=np.arange(11,20,dtype=np.float32)
    c=np.zeros(9, dtype=np.float32)

    c=test(a,b)

    print(c)

main()
```

Comment: what happens if you remove the `@vectorize` decorator from the code and add `print(tuple.__itemsize__ * 4)` to your main function. What does it print?

Comment: it simply prints 16 and then the result stored in the variable "c"

Comment: Ok so you have a 32 bit python installation. That is why CUDA is disabled

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am runnig [sic] a x64 Windows version and i've [sic] checked the python version too (which is also on x64). I am using a Nvidia gtx 960m, with the latest drivers.

Despite this assertion, your Python interpreter is 32 bit. This was confirmed in comments by `print(tuple.__itemsize__)` returning 4. It would return 8 for a 64 bit Python interpreter.

You can clearly see [here](https://github.com/numba/numba/blob/210d8397a79f0379ebbab753c3d611ac6a98eb48/numba/config.py#L266) that `NUMBA_DISABLE_CUDA` can only be set within Numba if it is set in the host environment, or by having a 32 bit Python interpreter, with is determined by the value of `tuple.__itemsize__` within Numba. It is the latter in the case.

> I've tried to search for this problem for over two weeks now, but didn't find any solution that might work

There is no solution because any version of CUDA which  is new enough to work with Numba doesn't support 32 bit environments on Windows. This was deprecated a long time ago on Windows platforms. Your only recourse is to install a native 64 bit version of Anaconda with a 64 bit Python interpreter and associated libraries.